# Merging two tables into one using row wise subtraction

Tags: c#, linq, join, group-by

Please help me frame the linq for the following condition:

tbl1:

```
ID | Total
1     20.00
2     90.00
3    130.00
```

tbl2:

```
ID | Total
1     10.00
2     30.00
```

difference table:(tbl1-tbl2)

```
ID | Total
1     10.00
2     60.00
3    130.00
```

Kindly let me know how to frame this.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: That's a left-join. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

Comment: What if `tbl2` has an ID that `tbl1` does not have?

Comment: in that case still tbl1 - tbl2 holds as the value from tbl1 is 0. Say, tbl1 has no row for ID=5, but B has a row, ID=5,Total=60 .Then the diff row should be like, {5,-60}

Comment: are you confusing the term `Merge` with using a `Join` or perhaps `UNION` I think that you should investigate and or read up on how to do Table Joins

Answer (score 2):

In SQL world, you take tbl1 and `union all`  tbl2 with the negative total, then you `group by` the `id` summing the value

```
var query = from x in tbl1.Concat(tbl2.Select(t => new { ID = t.ID, Total = -t.Total }))
            group x by x.ID into x
            select new
            {
              ID = x.Key,
              Total = x.Sum(y => y.Total)
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a full outer join, which can be represented as the union of a left outer join and a right outer join.

```c-sharp
class DataModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() { return string.Format("{0}:{1}", ID, Total); }
    public override int GetHashCode() { return ID; }
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        DataModel otherModel = other as DataModel;
        if (otherModel == null) return false;
        return ID == otherModel.ID;
    }
}

IEnumerable<DataModel> table1 = new List<DataModel> {
    new DataModel { ID = 1, Total = 20m },
    new DataModel { ID = 2, Total = 90m },
    new DataModel { ID = 3, Total = 130m }
};
IEnumerable<DataModel> table2 = new List<DataModel> {
    new DataModel { ID = 1, Total = 10m },
    new DataModel { ID = 2, Total = 30m },
    new DataModel { ID = 4, Total = 15m }
};

IEnumerable<DataModel> leftOuterJoin = from one in table1
    join two in table2 on one.ID equals two.ID into temp
    from right in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new DataModel {
        ID = one.ID,
        Total = one.Total - (right == null ? 0m : right.Total)
    };
IEnumerable<DataModel> rightOuterJoin = from two in table2
    join one in table1 on two.ID equals one.ID into temp
    from left in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new DataModel {
        ID = two.ID,
        Total = (left == null ? 0m : left.Total) - two.Total
    };

IEnumerable<DataModel> difference = leftOuterJoin.Union(rightOuterJoin);
foreach (DataModel item in difference)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

The console output is:

```
1:10
2:60
3:130
4:-15
```

[See the fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wQhVcj)

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly. I have tested it. :)